# Java : About weakhashmap and lambda expression

Tags: java

While I'm studying about 'WeakHashMap', when null is assigned to the reference for lambda expression, it does not seem to be a target for garbage collector.

As null was assigned to 'key1' in the code below, it was expected that key1 object would be erased from the map. But it wasn't the result. Callee.CallBack is just FunctionalInterface.
May I know why?

```
@Test
void callBackWithWeakHashMap() {
    Map<Callee.CallBack, String> map = new WeakHashMap<>();

    Callee.CallBack key1 = callee1 -> System.out.println("input > " + callee1.getMsg());
    Callee.CallBack key2 = callee1 -> System.out.println("input > " + callee1.getMsg());

    map.put(key1, "1");
    map.put(key2, "2");

    key1 = null;
    System.gc(); // force garbage collect

    map.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println); // key1 was not expected to be output, but the result was not.

}
```

Comment: Note that `System.gc()` does not *force* to actually cleanup unused objects, it only suggests to the garbage collector to perform a cleanup.

Comment: Also, even if you could force garbage collection, a lambda is not necessarily garbage because the JVM is permitted to cache it for performance reasons. Since your two lambdas are identical, it's actually an implementation detail whether `key1` and `key2` are different objects in the first place.